Possible to automatically collapse columns based on weeks (Monday being shown), and also only the column for today to be seen?
I’m quite new in the Apps Script world. I believe my question would come in 2 different/separate scripts:

As a new tab is created based on the same template, and the dates are being filled in, could the columns automatically be grouped (by script), with only the “Monday” of that week being visible? (Not sure if this is feasible, also I reckon not with protected ranges?
Could only the column for today be shown via a checkbox? (as could be found scripted on this post). Miserably failed at trying for this so far

Notes:

Columns A and B have to remain visible (frozen)
Rows 1 to 5 as well (frozen)
Current tab is called “September”, but more tabs (October etc) would need to have the same script being run


I tried the second point, but all my columns were just gone. I’m sure the problem lies with me lol

Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide a sample sheet by editing your question above?

2 different/separate scripts: I don't see two scripts; I see two "states" based on a single checkbox and to which a single script can respond. "State#1": if "Today" is checked, then show "Today"; "State#2": if "Today" is NOT checked, then show Monday of the current week.

You have dates in columns; there is also a checkbox. If the status of the checkbox is:

checked then display the column for today's date
not checked then display the column for Monday of this week.

You have unsuccessfully tried to apply the code from How to show columns based on today's date, and hide the rest? (@Tanaike). The code in Google Sheets Apps Script to Find this weeks date for a day, as well as the follow weeks date for the same day was also helpful (@Kristkun).
Consider this script and the screenshots below ("today's date" = 13/9/2024)
The key is in the syntax for show Columns - specifically the number of columns to show.

showColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)

In the referenced script, the data for one day consists of three columns ("Time In", "Temp" and "Time Out" and the date is contained in the first column, so the script must display three columns:

sheet.showColumns(i + 3, 3)

In this case, the data for one day is a single column and this column also contains the date, so the script must display one column only.

sheet.showColumns(i + 3, 1)


function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e
  const sheet = range.getSheet()
  
  // checkbox is in B1
  if (range.getA1Notation() != "B1" || sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1") return

  // test if checkbox is checked (= "Today")
  if (!range.isChecked()) {
    // "Today" Checkbox is not checked, so display Monday
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: not checked, so display last Monday")

    // show all columns (unhide any columns)
    sheet.showColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2)
    // get the script timezone    
    var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: timezone = "+timeZone)
    var curr = new Date()
    var mondayDate = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()+1
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: curr = "+curr+", mondayDate = "+mondayDate+", curr get date = "+curr.getDate()+", day = "+(curr.getDay()+1)+", set date mondayDate = "+curr.setDate(mondayDate))
    var monday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(curr.setDate(mondayDate)), timeZone, "E d MMM")
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: monday = "+monday)

    // hide all columns
    sheet.hideColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2)

    // show Monday only
    sheet.getRange(5, 3, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 2).getDisplayValues()[0]
    .forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e == monday) {
        sheet.showColumns(i + 3, 1)
      }
    })
    return
  }

  // "Today" Checkbox IS checked, so today's date
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: today = checked so display today")
  
  // get the script timezone    
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: timezone = "+timeZone)
  
  // get the date
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "E d MMM")
  // Logger.log("now = "+now)

  // hide all the columns
  sheet.hideColumns(3, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 2)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+sheet.getRange(5, 3, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 2).getA1Notation())
  
  // show today's date
  sheet.getRange(5, 3, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 2).getDisplayValues()[0]
    .forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e == now) {
        sheet.showColumns(i + 3, 1);
      }
    })
}


Sample - Raw data


Sample - checked


Sample - unchecked


Hi @tedinoz - thanks a lot for the prompt response. It doesn’t seem to work on my end. Have added an editable sheet here

It shows the script ran successfully, but nothing moved.
I think it as a first step it might be easier to just focus on the checkbox when checked showing today only, and showing the original grid of dates if unchecked?

Regarding date format codes, Utilities.formatDate() "Formats date according to specification described in Java SE SimpleDateFormat class. Please visit the specification at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html".

It shows the script ran successfully, Not possible. 1) Line 5-range.getB5Notation() s.be range.getA1Notation() 2) Lines 21&45-ddd d mmm "ddd"=>"016" not "Mon"; "mmm"=>"minutes in the hour" not "Month in the year". 3) spreadsheet date format has an extra space after Month. e.g. "Mon 16 Sep "(= 11 characters) vs formatted date "E d MMM"="Mon 16 Sep"(10 characters). Please make these changes: edit Line 5=>getA1Notation, edit Lines 21&45=>"E d MMM "-note the extra space after the month, this will align to spreadsheet date format.
